# How to configure the note types in XFS with the 'WFS_CMD_CIM_CONFIGURE_NOTETYPES' command

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, xfs, cen-xfs

I want to configure specific note types during cash in operation

Input parameter should be in the following format: `LPUSHORT lpusNoteIDs;`

When I execute the below commands I get invalid data error (-52)

```
LPUSHORT* lpusNoteIDs;  
lpusNoteIDs = (LPUSHORT*)malloc(7*sizeof(LPUSHORT));
for(int i =0;i<7;i++)
{
    lpusNoteIDs[i]=(LPUSHORT)malloc(sizeof(USHORT));
}

lpusNoteIDs[0] = (LPUSHORT)0x2700;
lpusNoteIDs[1] = (LPUSHORT)0x2710;
lpusNoteIDs[2] = (LPUSHORT)0x2701;
lpusNoteIDs[3] = (LPUSHORT)0x2711;
lpusNoteIDs[4] = (LPUSHORT)0x2721;
lpusNoteIDs[5] = (LPUSHORT)0x2732;
lpusNoteIDs[6] = (LPUSHORT)0x2704;
hResult = WFSExecute(hService, WFS_CMD_CIM_CONFIGURE_NOTETYPES, (LPVOID)lpusNoteIDs, 400000, &res);
return (int)hResult;
```

I have even tried the below code but it gives me the same error

```
LPUSHORT* lpusNoteIDs;
USHORT abc[]={1000,9985,10001,10017,10034,9988};
lpusNoteIDs=(LPUSHORT*)abc;
hResult = WFSExecute(hService, WFS_CMD_CIM_CONFIGURE_NOTETYPES,(LPVOID)lpusNoteIDs, 600000, &res);
return (int)hResult;
```

In  **CIM Service Provider Implementation Specification** document it says:

> lpusNoteIDs :-Pointer to a NULL terminated list of unsigned shorts which contains the note IDs of the bank notes

Any help as to how the values must be passed would be very useful..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use WFMAllocate and WFMAllocateMore functions to allocate memory for XFS structures to transfer it between application and service provider.
Your example bellow:

```
LPUSHORT lpusNoteIDs = NULL;
const int countNotes = 7;
// Always use WFMAllocate* functions for XFS memory allocation
WFSRESULT hr = WFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(USHORT)*(countNotes+1), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT|WFS_MEM_SHARE, (void**)&lpusNoteIDs);

// Fill note ID's
lpusNoteIDs[0] = (USHORT)0x2700;
lpusNoteIDs[1] = (USHORT)0x2710;
lpusNoteIDs[2] = (USHORT)0x2701;
lpusNoteIDs[3] = (USHORT)0x2711;
lpusNoteIDs[4] = (USHORT)0x2721;
lpusNoteIDs[5] = (USHORT)0x2732;
lpusNoteIDs[6] = (USHORT)0x2704;

hr = WFSExecute(hService, WFS_CMD_CIM_CONFIGURE_NOTETYPES, (LPVOID)&lpusNoteIDs, 400000, &res);
```

Comment: When I check with bank notetype its shows me these type notes are configured..but they are not getting configured@Alex.D.Alexeev

Comment: @AlexDAlexeev its stores garbage values

Comment: I think there is a little mistake in code: hr = WFSExecute(hService, WFS_CMD_CIM_CONFIGURE_NOTETYPES, (LPVOID)lpusNoteIDs, 400000, &res); Remove & before lpusNoteIDs